# Infovis not Iterating over Root Node

Tags: javascript, html, json, infovis

I'm facing weird behaviour of Jit Infovis i'm using. I have two different html files that include a load json function from a Javascript file. The function is using infovis library to display a hypertree map from a json file. Both two html files load the same json file.

One html file has been succeeded rendering the map properly. But another one has not. It renders the map almost properly, but after i debugged it, i got it not iterating over the root node. Then, the root node becames inactive without label and clickability.

This is the js function i'm using.

```
        var labelType, useGradients, nativeTextSupport, animate;

        (function () {
            var ua = navigator.userAgent,
            iStuff = ua.match(/iPhone/i) || ua.match(/iPad/i),
            typeOfCanvas = typeof HTMLCanvasElement,
            nativeCanvasSupport = (typeOfCanvas == 'object' || typeOfCanvas == 'function'),
            textSupport = nativeCanvasSupport
            && (typeof document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d').fillText == 'function');
                        //I'm setting this based on the fact that ExCanvas provides text support for IE
                        //and that as of today iPhone/iPad current text support is lame
                        labelType = (!nativeCanvasSupport || (textSupport && !iStuff)) ? 'Native' : 'HTML';
                        nativeTextSupport = labelType == 'Native';
                        useGradients = nativeCanvasSupport;
                        animate = !(iStuff || !nativeCanvasSupport);
                    })();

                    var Log = {
                        elem: false,
                        write: function (text) {
                            if (!this.elem)
                                this.elem = document.getElementById('log');
                            this.elem.innerHTML = text;
                            this.elem.style.left = (350 - this.elem.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px';
                        }
                    };



                    function init(slugParam, pageParam) {
                        var isFirst = true;
                        var isSetAsRoot = false;
                        // alert(slugParam+ " | "+pageParam);

                        var url = Routing.generate('trade_map_buyer_json', { slug : slugParam, page : pageParam });
                        //init data
                        $.getJSON(url, function (json) {
                            var type = 'Buyer';
                            //end
                            var infovis = document.getElementById('infovis');
                            infovis.style.align = "center";
                            infovis.innerHTML = '';
                            // infovis.innerHTML  = '<img align="center" id="gifloader" style="margin-left:50%; margin-top:50%" src="{{ asset('/bundles/jariffproject/frontend/images/preloader.gif') }}" width="30px" height="30px"/>'
                            var w = infovis.offsetWidth - 50, h = infovis.offsetHeight - 50;

                            url = url.replace("/json/", "/");
                            window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", url);
                            //init Hypertree
                            var ht = new $jit.Hypertree({
                                //id of the visualization container
                                injectInto: 'infovis',
                                Navigation: {  
                                    enable: false,  
                                    panning: 'avoid nodes',  
                                },  
                                //canvas width and height
                                width: w,
                                height

    : h,
                            //Change node and edge styles such as
                            //color, width and dimensions.

                            Node: {
                                dim: 9,
                                overridable: true,
                                color: "#66FF33"
                            },
                        Tips: {  
                            enable: true,  
                            type: 'HTML',  
                            offsetX: 0,  
                            offsetY: 0,  
                            onShow: function(tip, node) {  
                                // dump(tip);
                                tip.innerHTML = "<div  style='background-color:#F8FFC9;text-align:center;border-radius:5px; padding:10px 10px;' class='node-tip'><p style='font-size:100%;font-weight:bold;'>"+node.name+"</p><p style='font-size:50%pt'>"+node.data.address+"</p></div>"; 
                            }     
                        },
                        Events: {  
                            enable: true,  
                            type: 'HTML',
                            onMouseEnter: function(node, eventInfo, e){
                                var nodeId = node.id;
                                var menu1 = [
                                {'set as Root':function(menuItem,menu) { 
                                    menu.hide();
                                    isSetAsRoot = true; 
                                    console.log(nodeId); 
                                    init(nodeId, 0);
                                }},
                                $.contextMenu.separator,
                                {'View details':function(menuItem,menu) { 
                                }}
                                ];
                                $('.node').contextMenu(menu1,{theme:'vista'});
                            } 
                        },  
                        Edge: {
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            color: "#52D5DE",
                            overridable: true,
                        },
                        onBeforePlotNode: function(node)
                        {
                            if (isFirst) {
                                console.log(node._depth);
                                var odd = isOdd(node._depth);
                                if (odd) {
                                    node.setData('color', "#66FF33"); // hijau (supplier)
                                } else {
                                    node.setData('color', "#FF3300"); // merah (buyer)
                                }
                                isFirst = false;
                            }
                        },
                        onPlotNode: function(node)
                        {
                            if (isSetAsRoot) {
                                var nodeInstance = node.getNode();
                                var nodeId = nodeInstance.id;
                                init(nodeId, 0); 
                                isSetAsRoot = false;
                            }
                        },
                        onBeforeCompute: function (domElement, node) {
                            var dot = ht.graph.getClosestNodeToOrigin("current");
                            type = isOdd(dot._depth) ? 'Supplier' : 'Buyer';
                        },
                        //Attach event handlers and add text to the
                        //labels. This method is only triggered on label
                        //creation
                        onCreateLabel: function (domElement, node) {
                            var odd = isOdd(node._depth);
                            if (odd) {
                                node.setData('color', "#66FF33"); // hijau (supplier)
                            } else {
                                node.setData('color', "#FF3300"); // merah (buyer)
                            }

                            domElement.innerHTML = node.name;
                            // if (node._depth == 1) {
                                console.log("|"+node.name+"|"+node._depth+"|");
                            // }
                            $jit.util.addEvent(domElement, 'click', function () {
                                ht.onClick(node.id, {
                                    onComplete: function () {
                                        console.log(node.id);
                                        ht.controller.onComplete(node);
                                    }
                                });
                            });

                        },

                        onPlaceLabel: function (domElement, node) {
                            var style = domElement.style;
                            style.display = '';
                            style.cursor = 'pointer';
                            if (node._depth <= 1) {
                                style.fontSize = "0.8em";
                                style.color = "#000";
                                style.fontWeight = "normal";

                            } else if (node._depth == 2) {
                                style.fontSize = "0.7em";
                                style.color = "#555";

                            } else {
                                style.display = 'none';
                            }

                            var left = parseInt(style.left);
                            var w = domElement.offsetWidth;
                            style.left = (left - w / 2) + 'px';
                        },

                        onComplete: function (node) {
                            var dot = ht.graph.getClosestNodeToOrigin("current");
                            console.log(dot._depth);
                            var connCount = dot.data.size;
                            var showingCount = '';
                            if (connCount != undefined) {
                                var pageParamInt = (parseInt(pageParam)+1) * 10;
                                var modulus = connCount%10;

                                showingCount = (pageParamInt - 9) + " - " + pageParamInt;

                                if (connCount -  (pageParamInt - 9) < 10) {
                                    showingCount = (pageParamInt - 10) + " - " + ((pageParamInt - 10) + modulus);
                                }
                            } else {
                                connCount = '0';
                                showingCount = 'No Connections Shown'
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    //load JSON data.
                    ht.loadJSON(json);

                    //compute positions and plot.
                    ht.refresh();
                    //end
                    ht.controller.onComplete();
                });
}

function isEven(n) 
{
   return isNumber(n) && (n % 2 == 0);
}

function isOdd(n)
{
   return isNumber(n) && (n % 2 == 1);
}
function isNumber(n)
{
   return n === parseFloat(n);
}

function processAjaxData(response, urlPath){
}

function dump(obj) {
    var out = '';
    for (var i in obj) {
        out += i + ": " + obj[i] + "\n";
    }
    out = out + "\n\n"

    console.log(out);

    // or, if you wanted to avoid alerts...

    var pre = document.createElement('pre');
    pre.innerHTML = out;
    document.body.appendChild(pre)
}
```

What's probably causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether there is conflict id. Basically infovis render each nodes by the id.
And if there is an DOM element that has the same id with one DOM element of a node. It would conflict and won't render

you can check it by duming dom element iterating over the nodes.